# How to mathematically represent an element within a member of a set?

Tags: set-theory

Let's say I have a set $F=\{(h_1,t_1), (h_2,t_2),\ldots, (h_n,t_n)\}$. Then how do I mathematically represent $h_i$, as an object within an element within the set $F$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, n$?

I think $h_i \in F$ is not a correct representation.

Comment: What do you mean by "represent"? It already has a name, it's called $h_i$.

Comment: You say "there exists a $t$ so that $(h_i, t) \in F$.  You can't say $h_i \in F$ because $h_i$ is not an element of $F$.  But $(h_i, t_i)$ is.  So you could just write $(h_i,t_i) \in F$.  But if you don't wish to talk about $t_i$ you can just say "there is some value $t$ where $(h_i, t)$ is an element of $F$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the question is to find a compact way to say "let $h_i$ be such that there exists a $t_j$ for which $(h_i,t_j) \in F$". If that's the case, then you could call the set $H_F$, so long as you explain this terminology. Or just call it $H$ if there would be no ambiguity.

Or: "let $(h_i, t_i) \in F$", even if you don't care about the $t_i$.